# Read all NSAttributedString attributes with their effective range

Tags: swift3, nsattributedstring

I am working on project which required to to find range of bold words in textview and replace their colour, I have already tried the following but it did not work.

```
.enumerateAttribute (NSFontAttributeName, in:NSMakeRange(0, descriptionTextView.attributedText.length), options:.longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { value, range, stop in

}
```

Comment: any other way than attributed text ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `value` argument passed to the closure of `enumerateAttribute` with `NSFontAttributeName` represents a `UIFont` bound to the `range`. So, you just need to check if the font is bold or not and collect the range.

```
//Find ranges of bold words.
let attributedText = descriptionTextView.attributedText!
var boldRanges: [NSRange] = []
attributedText.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, in: NSRange(0..<attributedText.length), options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) {
    value, range, stop in
    //Confirm the attribute value is actually a font
    if let font = value as? UIFont {
        //print(font)
        //Check if the font is bold or not
        if font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold) {
            //print("It's bold")
            //Collect the range
            boldRanges.append(range)
        }
    }
}
```

The you can change the color in those ranges in a normal way:

```
//Replace their colors.
let mutableAttributedText = attributedText.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
for boldRange in boldRanges {
    mutableAttributedText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: boldRange)
}
descriptionTextView.attributedText = mutableAttributedText
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the spectacular answer above, just a detailed code fragment which does this.  `x` is the mutable attributed string.  Hope it saves someone some typing.

```
let f = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
let fb = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
let fi = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

let rangeAll = NSRange(location: 0, length: x.length)

var boldRanges: [NSRange] = []
var italicRanges: [NSRange] = []

x.beginEditing()
print("----------------------->")

x.enumerateAttribute(
        NSFontAttributeName,
        in: rangeAll,
        options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired)
            { value, range, stop in

            if let font = value as? UIFont {
                if font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitBold) {
                    print("It's bold!")
                    boldRanges.append(range)
                }
                if font.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits.contains(.traitItalic) {
                    print("It's italic!")
                    italicRanges.append(range)
                }
            }
        }

x.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: f], range: rangeAll)

for r in boldRanges {
    x.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: fb, range: r)
}
for r in italicRanges {
    x.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: fi, range: r)
}

print("<-----------------------")
using.cachedAttributedString?.endEditing()
```

Note - this example **does not** deal with the annoying case of **both** bold and italic!  I figured it's more informative like this.